# Empty request body in onFetch method of serviceworker

Tags: post, service-worker

I am trying to make my website work offline, and while offline any POST request should be saved to a local database. Currently I have this code in my serviceworker to catch any requests:

```
self.onfetch = (event) => {
    switch (event.request.method) {
        case 'GET':
            return onGet(event);
        case 'POST':
            return onPost(event);
    }
};

async function onPost(event) {
    if (navigator.onLine){
        return;
    }

    event.request.clone().formData().then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
    })
}
```

I am trying to read out the data from the request, but the console.log returns an empty object. When looking at the failed request in DevTools the FormData is available. Is it not possible to read out the body when intercepting the request?

Comment: Could this be because when logging `FormData` instances, they always show up in the console as `FormData {}`? Could you try logging `[...data.entries()]`?

Comment: That was indeed the problem. Your solution works too but I found out by using Object.fromEntries(await event.request.clone().formData()) which suited the situation more.